# Name error displaying when running text.py file on CMD

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am calling this simple file text.py on command prompt.

When I directly ty to access it, windows is not able to recognize the file.

[image: Error 1]

I tried using the other alternative and called the file from python. But I get the error below:

> C:_data\xyx\Learn\Python>python Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar
>   25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD6 4)] on win32
>
> > > > text.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in  NameError: name 'text' is not defined

I am not sure what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `python text.py` or `py text.py`?

Answer (score 0):

Three ways you can call:

1. `python text.py` or `python3 text.py` (depends what is installed and set to PATH)
2. `py text.py`
3. `./text.py`        (work only if file has executable permission, executed from current folder, and shebang line is provided on very first line of text.py. If running from other folder, give full path. Also, it runs in bash, not in windows. If you have installed bash on windows, use command `bash` to go in bash and then run `./text.py`)

Comment: I am going to accept your answer, but have a additional query. Only the first command works. The rest of them don't. Is there a reason for that ? <https://imgur.com/a/ax0FS9q>

Comment: `py` and `python3` will work if path for them is set. They are used specially when you have multiple versions of python installed. Say, if you have python 2 and 3 both, you can run `py 2` to go on python 2 shell and `py 3` for python 3. And `./text.py` will work in bash, I have updated the answer for 3rd one